# A question regarding the Casimir operator on a $sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ module.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $M$ be a finite dimensional $sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ module. Let $c:M\to M$ be defined as $c(v)=(ef+fe+\frac{1}{2}h^{2}).v$. Here, $e$, $f$, $h$ denotes usual standard basis for $sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$. Prove the following:

(1) $c$ is a $sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ module homomorphism.

(2) If $M=V_{d}$, where $V_{d}$ is the representation space of the unique $d+1$ degree irreducible representation of $sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, then $c=\lambda _{d}.I$, and $\lambda_{d}=\frac{1}{2}d(d+2)$.

(3) Let us assume again that $M$ was as before ,that is, an arbitrary finite-dimensional $sl_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ module. Let $c$ as before, and assume that $c$ has only one eigen value that is say, $\lambda$. Then as we know from linear algebra that $M=Ker(c-\lambda I)^{m}$.

Let $U$ be a submodule such that $U\cong V_{d}$. Then from (2) deduce that $\lambda =\frac{1}{2} d(d+2)$.

Here $c$ is popularly known as the casimir operator. Now, I have already solved (1) and (2). My problem lies with question (3). As $U$ is a irreducible submodule,  if $U$ would have been invariant under $c$, that is, $c(U)\subset U$, then $c$ would have been also a $sl_{2}(\mathbb{c })$ module homomorphism from $U\to U$. Then as $U\cong V_{d}$, and we know $c=\lambda _{d}I$, and $c$ has only one eigen value $\lambda$, it is clear that $\lambda=\lambda _{d}$. But in general situation $U$ maynot be $c$ invariant. So, in this case is $U$, c-invariant. If yes why? If no, what is the way to solve the 3rd part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $e$, $f$, and $h$ all preserve $U$ then so does $c$ because of how it is constructed (as a sum of compositions of these operators).

Comment: Oh! I didn't make use of the definition of the operators. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e$, $f$, and $h$ all preserve $U$ then so does $c$ because of how it is constructed (as a sum of compositions of these operators). – Nate 18 hours ago